# How to pass query result data to the view in Express.js and Mysql

Tags: javascript

I am trying to display my query result in my view,but nothing seems to be working as i m new to this , I can see the result in the console log but not on my html file 3

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var connection = require('../connection');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

connection.query('SELECT * FROM articles',function(error,results,fields){
 if(error) throw error;

  console.log('Data received from Db:\n');
  console.log(results);

  res.render('index', {data:results,error:null});
   });



});

 module.exports = router;
```

and my view is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <title></title>
 <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>test</h1>
  <p>Welcome to <%= ??????? %> </p>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Thanks

Comment: i am assuming you are using ejs? i thats the case rename your index.html to index.ejs and make sure is in the views folder

Comment: my index.html is index.ejs. i dont seem to be able to pass the query result to my view

Comment: js: res.render('index', {data:JSON.stringify(results),error:null});
ejs:<p>Welcome to <%= data %> </p>
what happens?

Comment: nothing happens, i dont get an error either , just no output , my sql query returns two articles with title and body , i want to display the title and the body. It should be simple but nothing is happening , this is what gets printed in my command line from result 'code''[ RowDataPacket {
    id: 1,
    title: 'First Title',
    body: 'is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum.','code'

Comment: do you get the page rendered at least?

Comment: Page renders but nothing is displayed between the html tags,  for instance I want to display the title ,  if I say data.title, then I get an undefined error. I'm using mysql

Answer (score 0):

I use EJS as template engine here but you can use any others to.

your index.js route file code:

```
var express = require('express');
const sql = require('mssql');
var router = express.Router();

 router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
 var myArr= [];
 const request = new sql.Request();
 request.query("SELECT * FROM Student", function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (err) {
    res.status(500).json({"status_code": 500,"status_message": "internal server 
  error"});
  } else {
  // Loop on each row
  var lng = rows.recordsets[0].length;
  var rc = rows.recordsets[0];
  for (var i = 0; i < lng; i++) {

    //Create an object to save current row's data
    var person = {
      'LastName':rc[i].LastName,
      'FirstName':rc[i].FirstName
    }
     // Add object into array
     myarr.push(person);
 }

// Render index page using array 
  res.render('index', {"myres": myarr});
}
});
});
 module.exports = router;
```

and your index.ejs should be like bellow:

```
 <ul>
  <%for(let i=0; i<myres.length; i++){%>
   <li><%=myres[i].LastName%></li>

  <%}%>
 </ul>
```